# NetSuite doesn't update the last modified date if the Customer Balance is changed

Tags: netsuite

I faced the following problem in NetSuite.
If the Customer balance is changed, NetSuite doesn't update the last modified date for this Customer.

For example:
I have two Customers. Each Customer has two open invoices.

From Customer1, I moved the invoice to Customer2.
The balance for Customer1 is changed, but the last modified date is not changed.
This negatively affects the correct use of the data via API because we don't understand that the data for Customer1 is changed.

As I understood it is correct behavior in NetSuite because balance is not data that is on the customer, it's a number calculated from other records.

In this case, how I can receive information that the Customer Balance is changed?

Comment: A transaction linked to the customer in some way will have changed / been created. In the UI that would on a the Customer form under Sales tab, Transaction sub tab.

Comment: Brian,

Does NetSuite have a request that allows receiving information that the Customer Balance is changed?
I mean the request via API.